# How to enable a 'take picture' button while choosing pictures in Camera Roll

Tags: ios, xcode

My colleague is developing an iOS app in Xcode. 
How can we enable a 'taking a picture' button (the left top corner) at the same page as Camera Roll while choosing pictures to upload?

Similar to this one: http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Facebook-camera.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots you have posted are not a standaard iOS SDK image picker control, but a custom build image picker.

Therefor you can not just enable the "take picture" button, since it is not available in the standaard image picker.

Comment: OK, thanks. But how can I find this custom build image picker?

Comment: Well you will have to contact the developers of that specific app if they are willing to share the code with you or you might have to build it yourself.